# How to read values from nested json object in vb?

Tags: json, vb.net

I have following values which return as json, from that i read first level values, but how to read nested level value from that json value ?
From below json i can read Inv_Date value and Inv_Number value, but how to loop and read all values from "row" like "S No","Description","Quantity" etc .

I want to loop and read those values using vb

```
  {"result": [
 {
"Inv_Date": {
  "value": "15-Jul-2019",
  "confidence": 0.97155118538848806,
  "page_index": 1,
  "coordinate": [
    1209,
    255,
    1314,
    270
  ]
},
"Inv_Number": {
  "value": "49994",
  "confidence": 0.811458509553224,
  "page_index": 1,
  "coordinate": [
    1023,
    189,
    1145,
    209
  ]
},
"line_items": [
  {
    "row": {
      "S No": "Part Drawing",
      "Description": "RACK TUBE VERSA Yotr Part No. : -340701490 Drawing Issue Number : -0",
      "Quantity": "480.00",
      "Unit": "NOS",
      "Unit Rate": "53.2100",
      "Line_Item_Total": "25540.80",
      "Model": "",
      "Net Amount": "",
      "Item Code": "",
      "HSN": "",
      "Unit Price": "",
      "Configuration": "",
      "CGST Amount": "",
      "CGST Rate": "",
      "SGST Amount": "",
      "SGST Rate": "",
      "IGST Amount": "",
      "IGST Rate": "",
      "GST Amount": "",
      "GST Rate": "",
      "Service Tax Rate": "",
      "Service Tax Amount": "",
      "Serial Number": "",
      "Discount Rate": "",
      "Discount Amount": "",
      "Cess Rate": "",
      "Cess Amount": "",
      "Batch Number": ""
    },
    "page_index": 1,
    "coordinate": [
      252,
      671,
      1351,
      733
    ],
    "confidence": 0.555069966071009
  },
  {
    "row": {
      "S No": ".CGST @",
      "Description": ".CGST @ 14.00 %",
      "Quantity": "",
      "Unit": "",
      "Unit Rate": "",
      "Line_Item_Total": "3576.00",
      "Model": "",
      "Net Amount": "",
      "Item Code": "",
      "HSN": "",
      "Unit Price": "",
      "Configuration": "",
      "CGST Amount": "",
      "CGST Rate": "",
      "SGST Amount": "",
      "SGST Rate": "",
      "IGST Amount": "",
      "IGST Rate": "",
      "GST Amount": "",
      "GST Rate": "",
      "Service Tax Rate": "",
      "Service Tax Amount": "",
      "Serial Number": "",
      "Discount Rate": "",
      "Discount Amount": "",
      "Cess Rate": "",
      "Cess Amount": "",
      "Batch Number": ""
    },
    "page_index": 1,
    "coordinate": [
      252,
      784,
      1351,
      800
    ],
    "confidence": 0.56383986545314
  }
],
}
]}
```

i used following code to read inv date and inv number

```
            Dim clientPI As RestClient = New RestClient("https://sampleurl")
            Dim requestPI = New RestRequest(Method.POST)
            requestPI.AddParameter("name", "Aravind")
            requestPI.AddParameter("username", "aravind")
            requestPI.AddParameter("password", "aravind123")
            requestPI.AddParameter("id", "100")
            Dim responsePI As RestResponse = clientPI.Execute(requestPI)
            Dim StrReturnPI As JValue = responsePI.Content.ToString
            Dim serPI As JObject = JObject.Parse(StrReturnPI)
            Dim dataPI As List(Of JToken) = serPI.Children().ToList
            Dim output as String
            For Each item As JProperty In dataPI
                    item.CreateReader()
                    Select Case item.Name
                       Case "result"
                        output += "Document_id:" + vbCrLf
                        For Each comment As JObject In item.Values
                            Dim u As String = comment("Document_id")
                            output += u + vbTab
                            Dim invDate As JObject = comment("Inv_Date")
                            Dim invNumber As  JObject = comment("Inv_Number")
                            Dim invDateValue As String = invDate("value")
                            output += invDateValue + vbTab
                            Dim invNumberValue As String = invNumber("value")
                            output += invNumberValue + vbTab
                        Next
                   End Select
             Next
```

Thanks and regards
Aravind

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to do all of the manual parsing?  A feature of the json that won't work with a full VB object model?  I would expect a full object model to parse without needing much ceremony.

Comment: Take a look to [this Nu-Get package](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to work with JSON data

Answer (score 0):

i used following code get values from line_items.

```
Dim responsePI As RestResponse = clientPI.Execute(requestPI)
            Dim StrReturnPI As JValue = responsePI.Content.ToString
            Dim serPI As JObject = JObject.Parse(StrReturnPI)
            Dim dataPI As List(Of JToken) = serPI.Children().ToList
            Dim output as String
            For Each item As JProperty In dataPI
                    item.CreateReader()
                        Select Case item.Name
                           Case "result"
                            output += "Document_id:" + vbCrLf
                            For Each comment As JObject In item.Values
                                Dim u As String = comment("Document_id")
                                output += u + vbTab
                                Dim invDate As JObject = comment("Inv_Date")
                                Dim invNumber As  JObject = comment("Inv_Number")
                                Dim invDateValue As String = invDate("value")
                                output += invDateValue + vbTab
                                Dim invNumberValue As String = invNumber("value")
                                output += invNumberValue + vbTab
            'Here i loop again and retrieve all values from line_items  
            Dim dataPIa As JToken = comment("line_items")
                                          
            Dim dataPI1 As List(Of JToken) = dataPIa.Children().ToList
                            For i = 0 To dataPI1.Count - 1
                                For Each item1 As JProperty In dataPI1(i)
                                    item1.CreateReader()
                                    Select Case item1.Name
                                    Case "row"
                                    For Each comment1 As JProperty In item1.Values
                                    strallvalue = strallvalue & comment1.Name & " : " & comment1.Value.ToString & Environment.NewLine
                                    Next
                                    End Select
                                    Next
                                Next
                            Next
                       End Select
                 Next
```

Thanks and Regards
Aravind